# F# Filtering multiple years

Tags: list, function, filter, f#

My objective is to find the total amount of sun for the following years - 1960,1970,1980,1990,2000,2010. The data comes from a txt file and year, month, maxt, mint, afday, rain and sun have already been defined and take the relevant element from the tuple, then it ignores the rest.

```
// Example
let sun  (_,_,_,_,_,_,t) = t
```

I have found the total amount of sun for the year 1960. However, I am not sure how to find the remaining years.

```
let Q6 =
    ds |> List.filter (fun s-> year(s)=1960)
       |> List.sumBy sun
```

The above method is a boolean so wouldn't work for multiple years, what is the best method?
I believe the answer should be like this:

```
val Q6 : float list = [1434.4; 1441.8; 1393.0; 1653.0; 1599.5; 1510.2]
```

Comment: Please don't use a seven-component tuple to group simple data that doesn't have an obvious order. A record, or another type with named members, should be much more readable than the huge tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group them before applying the sum:

```
let Q6 =
    let years = [1960;1970;1980;1990;2000;2010]
    // or let years = [1960 .. 10 .. 2010]
    ds |> Seq.filter (fun value -> List.exists ((=) (year value)) years)
       |> Seq.groupBy year
       |> Seq.map (fun (year, values) -> year, Seq.sumBy sun values)
       |> Seq.toList
```

Here you will get something like:

```
val Q6 : (int * float) list = [(1960, 1434.4); (1980, 1441.8)]
```

If you don't want to have the year in the results you can remove the `year ,` from the lambda.

Comment: Thanks, my output is now all the years, how do I specify the year within the example you gave me?

Comment: Filter by the years you are interested before grouping. See the update.