# F# int list of two maximums

Tags: list, f#, maxby

Previous question: [F# Filtering multiple years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742791/f-filtering-multiple-years)

I need to return an int list of two years where the given years are the greatest amount of rainfall for any February within the data set.

So far, I have found the first year using List.maxBy but I believe this will only ever return the first maximum.

```
let rainfall
    ds |> List.filter (fun s-> month(s)=2)
       |> List.maxBy rain
       |> year
```

So how do I show both the first and second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably sort them descending:

```
let rainfall
    ds |> Seq.filter (fun s-> month(s)=2)
       |> Seq.sortBy (fun m -> -(rain m)) //Sort by the value of rain negated
       |> Seq.take 2
       |> Seq.toList
```

And then just take the first 2.

This will give you a list 2 items, the one with the most rainfall and the one with the second most.

If you want them as separate values you can do:

```
let most = ds |> List.nth 0
let secondMost = ds |> List.nth 1
```

Comment: List module doesn't have `List.take` function (at least in latest released F# version) but you can use `Seq.take`

Comment: @Petr Could you provide an example after the Seq.take 2. Have tried using head but getting the same as before.

Comment: @Petr thanks, I nearly always use Seq, forgot it wasn't on List.

Answer (score 0):

Use `List.sort` providing function that would sort by rain descending and take first 2 elements